# Generating Excel file with some number of sheets with a single template

Tags: c#, excel

i am generating an excel file with some number of sheets. I am using a template .xlt file which have one worksheet. Now I am able to generate the xl file with that template if there is only one worksheet in that excel file. But when I have to create more than one worksheet, I am unable to do that. Then the excel file do not use the template and instead use a blank worksheet. Can anyone point me to some reference where i can use the same template worksheet to create n number of worksheets in the same workbook.

Comment: Which method are you using to generate the Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it.

See the "Worksheet with Chart to Multiple Worksheets with Charts" sample on our [Excel Reporting Samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) page for an example or download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) to try it yourself.

Since the SpreadsheetGear API is very similar to the Excel API, you should be able to adapt the SpreadsheetGear code to work with Excel if you need to.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC